# MVC5 razor templates client server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use Razor for client and server side templates for MVC5? I now have to refactor a lot of my project to using AJAX, and client side template rendering. I was hoping to find something so that I won't have two separate template files for the same view. All my views are now made in Razor.

The project is using MVC5 and the latest Razor (version3)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talk about being able to parse the razor templates and use them like email templates for an example?

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is this: https://github.com/jchadwick/RazorClientTemplates but that seems to only work with MVC3 and Razor version 1. I want to render my razor templates in javascript by using a javascript object

Comment: Using the same razor template server and client side

Comment: What about this one https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine ?

Comment: The problem is, the template needs to be rendered in javascript. For example, I make a call to the server to get a json object, then, client side, I want to render a template using that json object

Comment: Are you required to return an JSON-serialized object? Why don't you instead return a partial view, bound to the model on the server side? If you need the JS-object you can still create it from the partial view. Alternatively you can make a second call to an action that renders the Json-object into a partial view.

Comment: Ok I think you guys are misunderstanding me. Let's say you have a simple guestbook, and when a user posts a new message, you don't want to refresh the browser, but instead use an AJAX call to insert it in the database, and then use javascript to show it on the screen. I could use something like Mustache.js to render the "guestbook-post-template". But then I would have that template 2 times, 1time in server (with razor) and one time in client (with mustache). That's the problem, I don't want to write my templates two times!

Answer (score 1):

I doing the same investigation. Razor template rendering in javascript would be the ideal soluion...
Maybe this could be the good enter point

http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=375

https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash

I also looking for template engine which could work for both MVC5 server and client side. I found jade template engine and Spark framework for asp. Spark can undestnd Jade sintax and javascript has Jade template engine. It seams like I found the solution but Spark framework stop developing on mvc3 stage... the same thing for nustache. It is annoying stopper.